# Publisher VBA to save as image

Tags: vba, ms-publisher

I've developed the following code to save all publisher files in the current directory as an image, however it seems to take a long time to run through. Also, I can't figure out a way to exclude the current file that the macro is running from. Anyone got any ideas?

```
 Sub Looptest()

      Dim MyFile As String, Sep As String
      Dim objPub As Object
      Set objPub = CreateObject("Publisher.Application")
      Dim folder As String
      folder = CurDir()
    If Len(Dir(folder & "\" & "jpg", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir (folder & "\" & "jpg")
    End If


       Sep = Application.PathSeparator

      If Sep = "\" Then
         ' Windows platform search syntax.
         MyFile = Dir(CurDir() & Sep & "*.pub")

      Else

          MyFile = Dir("", MacID("XLS5"))
      End If

      ' Starts the loop, which will continue until there are no more files
      ' found.


      Do While MyFile <> ""
    'If MyFile = "macro.pub" Then
    'GoTo ContinueLoop
    'End If

    Dim pubApp As Publisher.Application
    Dim pubDoc As Publisher.Document
    Dim folder2 As String
    folder2 = CurDir() & Sep & MyFile


    Set pubApp = New Publisher.Application

    pubApp.Open folder2
    'pubApp.ActiveWindow.Visible = True
    num = folder2
    pubApp.ActiveDocument.Pages(1).SaveAsPicture CurDir() & Sep & "jpg" & "\" & MyFile & ".jpg"
    pubApp.Quit
             MyFile = Dir()
    'ContinueLoop:
          Loop

       End Sub
```

I've commented out my attempt at skipping the file (called Macro.pub in this instance), as it just seemed to stall and not go anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Cr1kk0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is correct in all other respects, this might do the trick

```
If MyFile = ActiveDocument.FullName Then
    GoTo ContinueLoop
End If
```

I'm guessing your check fails because you're comparing a short file name to a full file name. (You could also just hardcode the entire path to macro.pub)